# Querying database based on map view using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

Currently I have a script where I query database based on an array of distances, increasing the radius  and stop the loop once I get some results. However I think it makes more sense in my case to query based on what is shown on the map, obviously within reasonable zoom level.

Is there a way to detect what radius I should use when a map loads at a particular zoom setting and how to capture it on map resize?

Comment: Try with: map.on('moveend', function() { 
     var extent = map.getBounds());
});

Comment: Oh cool, I'm getting some object back with NW and SE coords. How do I calculate what falls into that area? Sorry, it's probably basic but I never dealt with maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so you can get extent points by using:

```
map.on('moveend', function() { 
var southWest = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
var northEast = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
var northWest = map.getBounds().getNorthWest();
var southEast = map.getBounds().getSouthEast();
});
```

Then you have coordinates of your map extent. Now, depending on the application design, you can do "intersect" either on the client or on the back-end. If on the client side, I recommend using Turf.js, powerful library for spatial analysis. There you have intersect function. Or use post-gis, sde or whatever you are using for the backed to do calculations. But be careful because depending on the number of features it could take some time to calculate intersecting features.

Comment: OK, thank you. This is a lot to learn. I am trying to keep this project lightweight and aside leaflet.js I'm not really using any other libraries. In fact I ever decided to go with vanilla JS instead of my regular go-to jQuery. Most requests I handle with async AJAX posts and PHP/MySQL on the backend. I will give this function a try. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, in that case you could definitely check out intersects and contains methods of LatLngBounds object in leaflet. Check it out in documentation. You know bounds of your extent and then use bounds of every feature geometry to check if its intersects with extent. The only problem I see is point geometry features if you have them. Because you have no two points to create bounds. Maybe you could create bounds using its x and y and add tiny number to a coordinates just so you can get imaginary bounds for it. Probably someone here knows better way for point bounds, but that could work.

Comment: @Kumbra thanks for the tip, I'm trying to use it on another project... that gives me headaches.